# How to pass the delegate object to MVC Views.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, delegates

I have an delegate in my controller And I want that to be passed to my views to pass into my  settings.

I have tried assigning delegates to ViewData["delegateFunction"]=delegateFunction;

But That too is not valid idea..

I know this is a basic Question. But just learning about delegates.

Thanks in advance,
saravanakumar.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

I use the Model class for passing delegates to the View:

Model

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public Func<string, string> getUIName { get; set; }
}
```

Method declaration

```
public string concreteMethod_GetUIName(string text)
{
    return text;
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ExampleModel model = new ExampleModel { getUIName = concreteMethod_GetUIName };

    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model ExampleModel

@Model.getUIName("sample text")
```